# Google Analytics: Browsers used in a subdirectory

Tags: google-analytics, subdirectory

Our website has a specific subdirectory, that acts as an app that our customers use.

I need to figure what browsers are used within that subdirectory.

I go to Audience > Browser & OS. I then set add a Secondary Dimension to the results table for ` Behavior > Destination Page.

I then click 'advanced' in the upper right above the table.

I fill out the filter as follows:

Include > Destination Page > Matching RegExp > /Dashboard/(.*)

The results that this returns is a list of every URL that occurs under the Dashboard subdirectory. There are hundreds of URLs in there.

I need the results to roll up to the Dashboard directory. I need a list of what browsers are used on ANY screen within the Dashboard directory, not a list of every URL and what browser use it.

I am new to GA. What am I missing?

Comment: I also tried /Dashboard/.*

Comment: Some additional info: The overall goal here is to see what versions of IE we can stop supporting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Go to Behavior>Site Content>Content Drilldown
- Locate your directory (drill down to level 2/3 if need be)
- Apply Browser/OS as the secondary dimension.
- Filter for the concerned "directory" from the advanced filter.

Comment: That's close, but not quite it. This doesn't allow me to click into a browser and see what the most popular versions are.

Comment: For this level of detail, you would have to create a custom report.  
Goto  Customization>Custom Reports>"New Custom Report" and add all the dimensions (Content level, Browser, Browser Version)  as listed above . Also apply the filter for your directory and browser contains IE.